# Two very different brothers

Tags: riddle

Two brothers, young and old
More than 30 years apart
One is alive, the other is a memory

Nothing in common, except for one word
A love for playing and gaming
And a desire to be held by hands

One is family-friendly, the other is not
Many boys and men are among their fans
Who are these two brothers?

Old version of the riddle:

> Two brothers, young and old
>  Nothing in common, except for one word
>  One is family-friendly, the other is not
>  One is alive, the other is a memory
>
>  What are the names of these two brothers?
>
>  Additional hidden clue:
>  Both brothers like to *play game*s

Comment: My caring father is much younger than my long-lost, wicked uncle. And they are so different except for their family names. Do you take that as an answer?

Comment: "Nothing in common" would imply no parents in common. I suspect that the answers are not literal people.

Comment: @MikeQ You're right about that. :D They really have nothing in common... except for that one word in both their names.

Comment: ... as well as that additional hint I just added.

Comment: It might be a good idea to incorporate that hint into the main riddle rather than spoilertagging hint. Riddles should be uniquely solvable even *without* any extra hints.

Comment: @Randal'Thor That's why I had it in the spoiler tag, because I hoped it would be solvable even without it. It's my first riddle and I feared that the hints might be _too_ broad or cryptic to figure out the admittedly strange solution. Honestly, once it's found out or revealed what the two words are I'm looking for, you might go "OH COME ON, REALLY?!" I'll think about adding four more lines if it's not solved in three days.

Comment: I'd add more lines now. As it stands, there's nothing really pointing to anything terribly specific, and as such could be ignored, downvoted, or closed.

Comment: @feelinferrety Done so. Looks like I didn't give enough hints for my first riddle. Hopefully I didn't give too many now either...

Comment: For future reference, if you are ever unsure of a puzzle, even one that has already been posted, you are welcome to take it over to chat and ask the regulars to workshop it with you in a dedicated room. They can help you figure out the appropriate level of detail to avoid any ambiguity.

Comment: @feelinferrety Thank you, I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I already don't like my answer, but the brothers are...

> Game Boy and Play Boy

---

Two brothers, young and old
More than 30 years apart

> I don't feel like looking up the age of the later at work
>  But I do feel like frittering time away on riddles :D

One is alive, the other is a memory

> One has informative articles regarding living things, the other has electronic memory of digital things

Nothing in common, except for one word

> The word **Boy**

A love for playing and gaming

> The words **Play** and **Game**

And a desire to be held by hands

> Both are hand operated

One is family-friendly, the other is not

> Game Boy is more family friendly than the other one

Many boys and men are among their fans

> Boys like the former, men like the later. At least a long time ago they did.

Comment: Don't feel bad, cause your answer is correct! :D Only thing I don't like about your answer (besides the fact that you didn't add the year they were created in) is "One is alive, the other is a memory". It was actually meant to mean that the "dirty" one is still ongoing, while the other is not around anymore. You may argue it's still here because of Virtual Console, but the device itself certainly isn't around anymore.

Comment: Cool. I know Hugh's like 90, but one of those things is almost 30. I wasn't sure the other could really be 60+... And that was my other interpretation of  "One is alive, the other is a memory", but I liked smriti's take on "memory" more so I stole it.

Answer (score 3):

my first answer was

> wolf-ram

as for the new version, this is how far i got:
are they

> Light gun shooter(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_gun_shooter)

and

> wii remote

Two brothers, young and old
More than 30 years apart
One is alive, the other is a memory

> now a days the guns are not in use as they are not compatible with modern high-definition televisions

Nothing in common, except for one word
A love for playing and gaming
And a desire to be held by hands

> they both are held by hands, all they have common is they both are consoles

One is family-friendly, the other is not
Many boys and men are among their fans

> well, gun is NOT family friendly
> although i have my doubts about remote(considering how many arguments and fights it has started)

Although, I am not sure about the answer, I think I am close to the actual answer

Comment: Play games in case of Wolf could mean hunting. Game as in hunted animal.

Comment: Good guess for the old version of the riddle, but wrong unfortunately. :( I like how you interpreted "Nothing in common, except for one word" though, even if it's not the "right" interpretation for the solution. Didn't even think of that possibility.

Comment: You and mr23ceec got a lot closer to the solution. :) You are right that **one** of the brothers is related to gaming in some way, but the other brother isn't related to gaming at all, even if he loves "playing".

Answer (score 2):

Another way to answer

> Present and Past tense or time

Brothers:

> - Both time or tense same type or category
>   - Young: Present
>   - Old: Past

Nothing in common

> One word Tense or Time

Family Friendly

> Present, Gift, Exists, near

Alive and Memory:

> - Present: Alive, Exists
>  - Past: Memory, Old

Comment: I don't see how it relates to "Family Friendly"... Family? Seriously?

Comment: @William Nathanael Family Friendly is a way of speaking friendly not related offer gifts, presents, close,  neighborly, nice

Comment: Well, that makes sense. As a non-native English speaker, I must admit that I often get confused.

Comment: @yass Good try but no. :) Real answer is much simpler (kinda). Not sure if I should give this hint, but the two brothers are not an abstract concept like time but... something more tangible.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my thought...

> **Sonic the Hedgehog** and **Jabba the Hutt**.

Two brothers, young and old

> **Sonic** is young: hedgehog lifespans are generally less than ten years; Sonic is depicted as a youthful character; and the first Sonic game debuted in 1991, so the franchise is only 26.
>  **Jabba** was roughly 600 years old by the time of Episode VI, making him quite old indeed.

Nothing in common, except for one word

> The only thing they have in common is the word "the"!

One is family-friendly, the other is not

> **Sonic** is aimed at kids.
>  **Jabba** is a ruthless gangster type who hires hit men and keeps slave women literally chained up by his side - when he's not feeding them to his pet rancor or to a Sarlacc. He's not particularly family friendly!

One is alive, the other is a memory

> The **Sonic** franchise and character are both alive and well.
>  **Jabba**, meanwhile, is dead - throttled to death by Leia, using her own chain.  Thus he is now but a memory.

What are the names of these two brothers?

> Sonic the Hedgehog and Jabba the Hutt.

Additional hint:

> *Both brothers like to play games*
>  **Jabba** is a gambler. He's also appeared in Star Wars video games.
>  **Sonic** is a video game character, so literally plays games. He has also appeared in "Mario vs Sonic" titles in which the two characters compete in Olympic Games themes mini games.

Comment: Are you trying to imply that this is too broad? ¬‿¬

Comment: I thought this as plausible an answer as any other. So, *yes*.

Comment: @Rubio Definitely the weirdest solution so far. XD Given the vagueness of the old version of my riddle though, I can't exactly blame you. Hopefully the new version will narrow the possible solutions down a little. :)

Comment: Amusingly, this still almost works for the new version.

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> Hangman

Two brothers, young and old

> Hangman the game is relatively young (i.e. new) whereas hanging people as a death sentence happened a long time ago

Nothing in common, except for one word

> The game is about guessing letters, not killing people so there's nothing in common there.

One is family-friendly, the other is not

> Hangman the game is family friendly, hangings aren't.

One is alive, the other is a memory

> Two meanings here, hangman the game is still something we do today, i.e. alive, also no one dies playing hangman, so that's alive too.

What are the names of these two brothers?

> Hangman

Comment: Very creative solution. I would say it's wrong because it's not the solution I wanted, but your solution ticks all the boxes of the old version of my riddle that I still consider it somewhat "correct". Definitely a good try.

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> Nintendo Switch and FamiCom?

Two brothers, young and old
More than 30 years apart

> indeed 34

One is alive, the other is a memory

> not literally alive, but certainly in production

Nothing in common, except for one word

> Nintendo

A love for playing and gaming

> gaming consoles, duh

And a desire to be held by hands

> Famicom is not a handheld device, but it does have a very tactile joystick (much moreso than, say, a keyboard)

One is family-friendly, the other is not

> *Fami*Com!

Many boys and men are among their fans

> stereotypically. Though studies show that the difference isn't actually significant.

Comment: You are very close, one of the brothers indeed has something to do with gaming (and Nintendo specifically), the other is completely unrelated to gaming however. :)